# How can I restore VM on a new Hyper-V server?

Tags: hyper-v, virtual-machines, reinstall

I was working gladly with my VM on my local Hyper-V server. But, after installing some updates on the host the system only show the famous blue screen. I couldn't start my host so I reinstalled it and configured as new Hyper-V server.

My VM was in a another disk to prevent this happening but I don't know how to add it as a new VM on new server. In addition, this VM has various snapshots so, how can I add this VM to my new Hyper-V server?

UPDATE:
I can't do Export/Import because my server crashed before I can't do it.

Comment: Do you still have thh VHD file where you loaded your guest OS?

Comment: Yes, the avhd files (for snapshots) too.

Answer (score 1):

First things first - make sure you back up your Hyper-V VHD just incase.

If you know the configuration of your previous Hyper-V I would advise that you simply create a new Hyper-V on the server and attach the existing hard drive too it. It is probably the quickest way to bring things back as I understand your situation.

If you don't know the configuration you will probably need to take to try and re-create the configuration through trial and error.

By doing this you will likely change the machines MAC address - I don't know if that matters too you.

Comment: That was a great idea for vm without snapsohts. I made the test with the file with vhd extensions and works perfectly, but this is the first snapshot I did.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/08/26/hyper-v-export-import-part-1.aspx) and [this](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/virtual_pc_guy/archive/2008/08/27/hyper-v-export-import-part-2.aspx)

Comment: I can't do export because my host crashed and I had to reinstalled and configured it.

Comment: The articles talk about IMPORT as well.

Comment: Doing a reading again on the articles, I think you mean to do an export operation manually, don't you?